# Move a page up based on input Click Event in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I implemented NPM Onscreen keyboard in my angular application. Its working good.but i have some issue while i choose the input from bottom of the page. the input is not visible bcz keyboard come over the input. so i need to do a scroll up or create empty space in bottom of the page while i do a click event. how to achieve this thing? any other suggestion?

here am providing a stackblitz url for ur reference:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/onscreen-keyboard-qfg8n4?file=src%2Fkeyboard%2Fkeyboard.component.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.activeElement.scrollIntoView({block:"center"})` in **keyboard.component.ts**

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.keyboardSubscription = this.keyboard.keyboardRequested.subscribe(
      (show) => {
        if (show) {
          document.activeElement.scrollIntoView({ block: 'center' });
          this.shown = true;
        } else {
          this.shown = false;
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

That attempts to scroll the element in focus to the center of the screen (vertically). You could use other paramaters as well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Then just make sure you have enough space at the bottom of your page  with a dummy div.

```html
<div>
  <input appOskInput type="text" />
</div>
<div>
  <input appOskInput type="text" />
</div>
<div>
  <input appOskInput type="text" />
</div>
<div>
  <input appOskInput type="text" />
</div>
<div>
  <input appOskInput type="text" />
</div>
<div style="height:250px"></div>
<app-keyboard></app-keyboard>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/onscreen-keyboard-ewduwg?file=src/keyboard/keyboard.component.ts

**Edit: Dynamically adding the spacer**

Seperate the keyboard html into a spacer and the keyboard, bind the `shown` class to the `shown` variable

```html
<div class="spacer" [class.shown]="shown"></div>
<div class="keyboard" [class.shown]="shown">
...
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.spacer {
  display: none;
  height: 240px;
}

.spacer.shown {
  display: block;
}

.keyboard {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #eee;
  position: fixed;
  height: 200px;
  width: 80%;
  left: 10%;
  bottom: -240px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.keyboard.shown {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Then we need to force change detection before attempting to scroll

```js
export class KeyboardComponent implements OnInit {
  shown: boolean;

  private keyboardSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef,
    private keyboard: KeyboardService,
    private changeDetect: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.keyboardSubscription = this.keyboard.keyboardRequested.subscribe(
      (show) => {
        if (show) {
          this.shown = true;
          this.changeDetect.detectChanges();
          document.activeElement.scrollIntoView({ block: 'center' });
        } else {
          this.shown = false;
        }
      }
    );
  }
...
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/onscreen-keyboard-ewduwg?file=src/keyboard/keyboard.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.but am expecting when click input that time the empty space have to come, after enter the value the empty sapce should not to come

Comment: Added a stackblitz where the spacer is appended / removed when the `show` variable changes

Comment: okay Thanks.let me check

Comment: Thanks its working fine but,i need number keyboard if input type is number and current key for other input type. can u pls help on that